# Set Row Color Using Epplus

Tags: c#, epplus

using Epplus how can I set an entire row background color to red?  I've got this

```
int rowNumber = ws.Cells[rowIndex].Value;
ws.Cells[rowIndex].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
```

but I'm getting error of

```
Can not convert from int to string on [rowIndex]
```

What is the proper way for me to set the row color using C# and epplus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ws.Cells` is an **`ExcelRange`** class, when you use `[ ]` with one parameter you should get a string of `Address`:

```
  ws.Cells[string Address]
```

You can use this with `rowIndex` and `col` to reach a cell and then add color:

```
int col = 1;
int rowIndex = 1;

//in SetColor Method use ColorRgb
ws.Cells[rowIndex, col].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));
ws.Cells[rowIndex, col].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

If you want to modify the color to multiple rows instead of a cell, use this:

```
ws.Cells[int FromRow, int FromCol, int ToRow, int ToCol]
```

With this, you can reach all of first twenty columns and set the color for them.

Comment: i want to highlight the entire row, not the column

Comment: Can I do the first 20 columns?

Comment: use this to reach multiple rows and columns ws.Cells[int FromRow, int FromCol, int ToRow, int ToCol]